# How to create a git patch from the committed changes

Tags: git, git-patch

I use Android Studio to create a patch file from uncommitted changes. In this case, I need to create a patch file from my last committees.

Answer (score -1):

commit_count: last commit count

```
git diff HEAD~commit_count > name.patch
```